# getting vars from $_SESSION throws an error

Tags: php

while passing `$_SESSION['var']` to function, if `$_SESSION['var']` is unset, I'm getting Notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: var in scripname.php on line 49
```

Is there safer way to obtain `$_SESSION['var']`, which will give me `0` if `$_SESSION['var']` is unset?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$var = isset($_SESSION['var']) ? $_SESSION['var'] : 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['var']))
{
    echo "session is set";
}
else
{
    echo "session is not set";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['var'])){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!array_key_exists('var',$_SESSION))
{
    $var = 0;
}
else
{
    $var = $_SESSION['var'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['var']))
    // do
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$var = @$_SESSION['var'];
```

Comment: You will not get 0 if var is not set, but why you need that 0? Just use that empty $var like if ($var){ then do what you need }